# Four vectors and the Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, vectors, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

From Lifshitz and Landau Vol.2.

The Lorentz transform of Cartesian coordinates:

$$x=\frac{x^{\prime}+V t^{\prime}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^{2}}{c^{2}}},} \quad y=y^{\prime}, \quad z=z^{\prime}, \quad t=\frac{t^{\prime}+\frac{V}{c^{2}} x^{\prime}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$$

The Lorentz transformation of Four Vectors:

$$
A^{0}=\frac{A^{\prime 0}+\frac{V}{c} A^{\prime 1}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^{2}}{c^{2}}}}, \quad A^{1}=\frac{A^{\prime 1}+\frac{V}{c} A^{\prime 0}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^{2}}{c^{2}}}}, \quad A^{2}=A^{\prime 2}, \quad A^{3}=A^{\prime 3}
$$

Comparing $t$ with $A^0$ and $x$ with $A^1$, the Lorentz transformations seem to differ. Why?

Comment: because $x^0=ct$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, $(t,x,y,z)$ is not a 4-vector.
But $(ct,x,y,z)$ is a 4-vector.

When you write the Lorentz transformation for $(ct,x,y,z)$
$$
ct=\frac{ct'+\frac{V}{c}x'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^{2}}{c^{2}}}},
\quad x=\frac{x'+\frac{V}{c}ct'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^{2}}{c^2}}},
\quad y=y', \quad z=z'
$$
then you see, now it is exactly the same transformation as for
the 4-vector $(A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3)$.